# Which version of Lineage OS do I use for Samsung s4 SPRINT?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, sprint, builds

Previously I used `jfltespr`. But Lineage OS [doesn't show any builds for that](https://download.lineageos.org/jfltespr). Did one of the other builds replace that?

- jfltexx
- jfltevzw
- ks01lte

jfltexx sounds appropriate but I can't find anything that confirms that it will work on S4 Sprint.

Comment: The XX one is only for non-CDMA models, and most of the time only international ones (not even T-Mo). Sprint variant might be having problems related to cellular stuff - there isn't even an *unofficial* build on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-sprint). There are other N ROMs there that are tailored for the variant though.

Comment: Could this be an opinionated post? Doesn't seem to ask a specific question related to android.

Comment: Continuing on @AndyYan 's comment, there is a custom ROM named [Oct-N](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-sprint/orig-development/rom-team-octos-oct-n-t3537546). Quoted from the XDA thread:

"Q: What code is Oct-N based on?
A: This version of Oct-N is based on LineageOS 14.1"

Comment: @user145490 no, it's a purely objective matter to ask which version of a rom you use on a specific build. It's not an opinion that an Exynos will not run an ARM build, it's a unopinionated fact.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Okay. Understood your point of logic. Just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the [unofficial "Optimized LineageOS" ROM by JDCTeam](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9505-orig-develop/jdcteam-optimized-cyanogenmod-14-0-t3479888/) for several months now, and it has been working wonderfully, thank G‑d. It is a ROM for several S4 models (I think this is called a "unified" aka `jflte` build), including the `jfltespr` (which does not yet have its own official LineageOS ROM, as of 2017/09). It has generally been updated monthly.

`jfltespr` is the code name for the sprint variant of the Galaxy S4, and`jfltexx` is the codename for the international S4. ROMs for the `jfltexx` will most likely not work with the `jfltespr`, since they use different cellular radio protocols. (When I tried to install the `jfltexx` version on a `jfltespr` device using TWRP, this was detected and an error message was issued saying it could not install on the device since was the wrong device type).

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, LineageOS 16 is officially supported for the Sprint Galaxy S4.

https://download.lineageos.org/jfltespr

Note that I had trouble installing this image using the last available version of TWRP for the Sprint S4, and had to flash the lineageOS recovery image before I could get the rom to flash.